# What is Event in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, events

in c# what is Event?  Is it similar to [ActionScript Event](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html) ? Is it different? In what?

Comment: This might help : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is events in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951927/what-is-events-in-c)

Comment: I'm sorry to have to break this to you, but learning a programming language playing 20 questions is not going to work. You really do need to read up on the language before you go on.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen  87+ actually=)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> An event in C# is a way for a class to
>   provide notifications to clients of
>   that class when some interesting thing
>   happens to an object. The most
>   familiar use for events is in
>   graphical user interfaces; typically,
>   the classes that represent controls in
>   the interface have events that are
>   notified when the user does something
>   to the control (for example, click a
>   button).

This tutorial shows how to declare, invoke, and hook up to events in C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

An event in C# is a way for a class to provide notifications to clients of that class when some interesting thing happens to an object

An event is a mechanism via which a class can notify its clients when something happens. For example when you click a button, a button-click-event notification is sent to the window hosting the button. Events are declared using delegates.

for more detail : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csevents01.aspx

Answer (score 3):

"An event in C# is a way for a class to provide notifications to clients of that class when some interesting thing happens to an object. The most familiar use for events is in graphical user interfaces; typically, the classes that represent controls in the interface have events that are notified when the user does something to the control (for example, click a button)."

From here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(VS.71).aspx

Yes, it is similar to ActionScript Events.

Answer (score 1):

as the Event class is passed as a parameter into an event listener I would say [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN is an excellent place to start.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Short version:  Events are a conceptual nicety that allows simpler implementation of a callback/subscription model for notification.

Answer (score 1):

Event is programming construct by which a class or an object, to be specific, inform(notify) a particular change of state to a list of subscribed objects in a multicast fashion.